# Why does $x!$ grow faster than $(x/2)^{(x/2)}$ but slower than $x^x$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble understanding this.

I understand the reasoning about why $x!$ grows slower than $x^x$. However, I'm not sure how to show that $x!$ grows faster than $(x/2)^{(x/2)}$. I was thinking that the $(1/2)^{x/2}$ term would end up affecting the function, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps taking naturals logs is illuminating:

$\ln (x!) = \sum_{k=1}^x \ln(k)$.

$\ln (x^x) = x \ln x \geq \ln(x!)$.

$\ln(x/2)^{(x/2)} = (x/2) \ln (x/2)$. We can see there are half as many logarithms here as in the sum $\sum_{k=1}^x \ln(k)$. We compare our $\ln(x/2)$ with the upper half of the $\ln(k)$ logarithms, i.e. $x\geq k \geq floor(x/2)$. When $x$ even you can see every $\ln(k)$ logarithm is greater than the $\ln(x/2)$. For $x$ odd, we add the extra logarithm $\ln((x-1)/2)$. It is fairly clear the summed logarithms still win.

Answer (score 0):

The change in the exponent from $x$ to $x/2$ is enormous.  The $2$ in the denominator doesn't matter so much.  We can use Stirling's approximation for the factorial
$$x! \approx \frac {x^x}{e^x}\sqrt{2 \pi x}$$ to see
$$(x/2)^{(x/2)} \lt x^{(x/2)}=\sqrt{x^x}\lt x! \lt x^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $x$ even, for simplicity:

One way to see that $x!$ is way bigger than $(\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{x}{2}}$ is by looking at the last $\frac{x}{2}$ numbers of the product $$x!=1\cdot 2\cdot \dots (\frac{x}{2})(\frac{x}{2}+1)(\frac{x}{2}+2)\dots \cdot x.$$
In the following product, each factor is bigger than $\frac{x}{2}$, so 
 $$(\frac{x}{2}+1)(\frac{x}{2}+2)\dots \cdot x\geq (\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{x}{2}}$$
So, $x!\geq 1\cdot 2\cdot \dots (\frac{x}{2})(\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{x}{2}} =(\frac{x}{2})!(\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{x}{2}}$.
So, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x!}{(\frac{x}{2})^\frac{x}{2}}\geq \lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{x}{2})! =\infty.$$ Which means that $x!$ grows faster than $(\frac{x}{2})^\frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is even then more than half  the $x$ terms in $$1\times 2 \times \cdots  \times \left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)\times \frac{x}{2}\times  \left(\frac{x}{2}+1\right)\times \cdots \times (x-1) \times x$$ are at least as big as $\frac x2$,  and one term is $1$ while the others are no bigger than $x$ so

$$\left(\tfrac x2 -1\right) !\times  \left(\frac{x}2\right)^{x/2} \times x \le x! \le 1 \times x^{x-1}$$

These are still very loose bounds but are enough for your result.  The argument for odd $x$ is similar.